# Eclipse - Add build path vs Add maven dependency. Any differences?

Tags: eclipse, maven, build

I have added a `Java` project dependency in `Maven` dependencies however if I add the same dependency in build path it works. What is the difference between these 2 methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding your project as maven dependency would mean that

1. You don't have to bundle your jar with your project.
2. You don't check in your .classpath and .project eclipse meta files in your source control
3. Any other programmer in your organization will be able to build your application.

You should not manually add jar file in eclipse build path. Its an anti pattern.

Both works because eventually your application need classpath which is set both by adding dependency manually as well as adding in build path.